# Entity framework eager loading new objects vs existing objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

Let's assume that I have two tables (sql first EF pattern)

```
create table test1 (
    id int identity (1, 1),
    name1 varchar(64),
    fk_table2 int
);

create table test2 (
    id int identity (1, 1), 
    name2 varchar(64)
);
```

Let's assume that we start with nothing in table `test1` and one record in `test2` with `id = 1` and `name2 = 'hello'`. The code snippet below fails due to a null reference as the link is not "loaded":

```
        using (var conn = new DatabaseObjects())
        {
            var t1 = new test1()
            {
                fk_test_2 = 1,
                name = "foo"
            };

            conn.test1.AddOrUpdate(t1);
            conn.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine(t1.test2.name2);
        }
```

I understand why this is happening. **My question** is how best do I now populate this "link" for it to be used? A simple but incorrect (overly inefficient) way is by adding a call to `conn.test2.Load()` before the `Console.WriteLine` call. A related question is, if the `test1` table is queried with an id of a previously created row as opposed to creating a new record, the link to `table2` will not be null (it is "lazy loaded"?). I don't understand how to reconcile this inconsistent behavior. Basically, I would like the behavior of querying an existing record where the link to the `test2` table exists after creating new records.

---

**Edit** to address comments below. Interestingly, when re-querying with the same `conn` object instance, the navigation properties are still null. But, if a new `DatabaseObjects` instance is created, the query returns an object with the navigation properties populated. Using the same example

```
using (var conn = new DatabaseObjects())
{
    var t1 = new test1()
    {
        fk_test_2 = 1,
        name = "foo"
    };

    conn.test1.AddOrUpdate(t1);
    conn.SaveChanges();

    var t2 = (from e in conn.test1 where e.id == t1.id select e).First(); 
    // t2 navigation properties are STILL null

    var conn2 = new DatabaseObjects();
    var t3 = (from e in conn2.test1 where e.id == t1.id select e).First();
    // t3 navigation properties are NOT null
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you are asking correctly. Are you asking why inserting a new `test1` linked to an existing `test2` doesn't populate the `test1.test2` navigation property to `test2` when `SaveChanges` is called?

Comment: I think that I understand why it doesn't populate the navigation property (efficiency?). My question is more about how to get the "new record" functionality to act more like the "query table" functionality. When creating a new record, the navigation properties are not populated but when querying with linq via `conn.table1` they are populated. I would like them to be populated when creating new records.

Comment: The easiest way to populate all the navigation properties on an insert might be to just re-query the entire object you just inserted.  If you have multiple navigation properties it will be more efficient than populating those individually.

Comment: There was too much to say for a comment so I edited the post. Basically, I wish this was the solution and maybe it is but I'm not sure how to get it to work that way.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'm still holding out hope that I don't have to use something like the solution by Rono ... what do you think?

Comment: I remember seeing something that lets you control how cached objects in a context are overwritten when requeried, but I don't remember what it is called. I will do some searching and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect a normal C# object to perform lazy loading. That doesn't happen. You always need a [proxy object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx) for that.

Ef will create a proxy if you use

```
var t1 = conn.test1.Create();
```

Now you'll see that *even without calling `SaveChanges`*, `test2` will be loaded only by accessing it. That is, if lazy loading is enabled on the context (which it is by default) and property `test2` is defined as `virtual`.

Comment: Thank you so much for a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just have to set the object yourself like this.

```
t1.test2 = conn.test2s.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == t1.fk_test_2)
```

I'm not aware of cleaner way to do this.